# JBOSS server taking to long to start

Tags: java, linux, performance, jboss, virtualhost

I have 4 standalone jboss5 nodes with same configuration. 2 nodes start within 6 minutes and other 2 are taking close to 37 minutes. Can you please provide some suggestions, also servers that are taking longer time are using more than 60% of swap space. When I compared garbage-collection stats first 2 nodes are taking  taking very long compare to other two. Below are my JVM settings.

/apps/jboss/jboss-5.0|-server-Xms7g -Xmx7g -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/apps/jboss/jboss-5.0/server/dev01/log -XverboseLog:/apps/jboss/jboss-5.0/server/dev01/log/gc.log -Xverbose:memory -XverboseTimeStamp

Thanks

Comment: At a glance I would say that the slow nodes do not have enough real memory in them. Get more...

Comment: @ Steve all four Nodes are running with 16G memory

Comment: You need to find out what is consuming swap because that is a performance killer. Are these virtual machines?

Comment: Yes these are virtual servers.

Comment: You need to provide a more thorough description of the hardware and *every* VM that has been set up on it - not just yours.

Comment: Indeed, conventional wisdom is that java processes should run entirely in available RAM - this is because on garbage collection the JVM does a more-or-less random walk of the entire heap. If the java process must page in and page out memory from/to disk to achieve this then it cannot be done in reasonable time. Can you post the output of  ps aux --sort rss so we can see what is taking up the other 9gb?